# UIAlertView Error

Tags: swift, uialertview

I am making a StockApplication using Swift and I am trying to make an Alert in the Portfolio and I am getting some errors. I have looked up the newest version of Alertview but nothing has worked so I was just looking for some help.

```
static func showAlert(title: String, message: String, caller: UITableViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        alertcontroller.addAction(okAction)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


    caller.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

My error I'm getting Use of Unresolved Identifier alertcontroller.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Pierce I updated my question.

Comment: Do you need to support iOS 7? If not, there is no need for all of the version checks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all split up and your declaration of `alertController` is scoped to only the first `if` statement.

The best approach would be to group all of your code together properly:

Swift 2:

```
static func showAlert(title: String, message: String, caller: UITableViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in
        // do something
        }
        alertcontroller.addAction(okAction)
        caller.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Fallback to UIAlertView on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Of course if you have no need to support iOS 7 then none of this is needed. Just do:

```
static func showAlert(title: String, message: String, caller: UITableViewController) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in
        // do something
    }
    alertcontroller.addAction(okAction)
    caller.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Swift 3:

```
static func showAlert(title: String, message: String, caller: UITableViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
            // do something
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        caller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Fallback to UIAlertView on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: That's still not updated for Swift 3 though. Swift 3 syntax would say `UIAlertActionStyle.default` and `caller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Pierce The OP posted Swift 2 code. The answer is Swift 2. The question makes no mention of using Swift 3.

Comment: I apologize if you thought I was criticizing. I was just making mention in case someone stumbled across this and needed to use Swift 3

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're instantiating `alertController` inside the chunk of code where you specify that it only be executed if iOS 8.0 is available. Try something like this instead:

```
var alertController:UIAlertController?

if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    // Do whatever else with the alertController
}
```

The problem based on what error you said you're seeing is that you're trying to present a `UIAlertController` at the end of your method named `alertController`, but it's telling you there isn't any property named `alertController`, which tells me that line of code where you instantiated it isn't being called, which means that if condition wasn't satisfied.

I would do this, it's updated and much simpler:

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String, caller: UITableViewController) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    caller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I will write some code that would work better, but let me ask you, why are you checking the iOS version? Are you using a device with something lower than 8.0?

Comment: No I just used this code from an older project and I need to update it. @Pierce

Comment: I am using the newest IOS.

Comment: See my updated answer. I think what you were trying to do was completely unnecessary.

Comment: It says UIAlertControllerStyle has no member "alert". On the next line it says expected Separator.

Comment: You might want to check the other answer posted. Are you using an older version of Swift?